# How can I switch a eclipse workspace without running the aplication?

Tags: eclipse, workspace

I am having a problem with eclipse on a dropbox shared workspace. My friend who shared the workspace with me said it has a bug. When I run eclipse (and I think that workspace is default), it just appears a window with nothing in it. So I think if I could change the workspace without running eclipse I could use another one with no bugs. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `-data` command line argument.

For example:

`-data path_to_workspace`

See http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Frunning_eclipse.htm.